# Convert date to format Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+010 to date yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I’m working on an Angular web app that has a date field form that uses angular material datepicker.
When the user selects a date with the datepicker, the value of the date I retrieve is in the format:
`Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+010`, I would like to convert into `yyyy/mm/dd`

Are there any built function to convert?

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular, but why not use standard Javascript built-in object `Date`?

Comment: `When the user selects a date with the datepicker, the value of the date I retrieve is in the format` <= Are you asking how to work with a proper date object or ISO8601 date string in the code behind? How and where specifically are you seeing the "the value of the date I retrieve"?

Comment: If you are asking about the code behind, ie. in the component or service classes, I recommend you work with the Date/DateTime types and not strings. For the angular material date picker see these adapters which offer various implementations of date libraries: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is if you are actually receiving that as a string or as a date object (they usually look like that when console.logged).

But anyway you should be able to convert using either Intl.DateTimeFormat, or more conveniently the Date method **toLocaleDateString**

```
let dateVar = 'Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+010');
let converted = new Date(dateVar).toLocaleDateString('sv-SE');
```

Here I chose 'Swedish' (sv) and location Sweden (SE) with gives "1970-01-01". I don't know if there is a country that has "1970/01/01" as standard. If not just keep Sweden as above and replace "-" with "/".

```
let dateVar = 'Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+010');
let converted = new Date(dateVar).toLocaleDateString('sv-SE')
.replaceAll('-','/');
```

Note: This **does not** change the time zone to Sweden, just the format of the date.

Comment: Thanks, I had used toLocaleDateString() but I didn’t give it a format in argument...
Finally I also found this solution: new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10)
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can leverage ISO string which is always the same format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

In order to format it as `YYYY/MM/DD` you simply:

- take first 10 characters of the ISO string
- replace all `-` with `/`

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    return date.toISOString().substring(0, 10).replaceAll('-', '/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use angular you can also use the [datePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe). This would also be my recommended approach.

```
 {{ youdate | date:'y/MM/d' }}
```

Otherwise you can do it like so using the date object, however I recommend a lib like [dayjs](https://day.js.org/) which provides a `format` function.

Note that `getMonth` is 0 based and `getDate` returns a number between 1 and 31

```js
const d = new Date();

const toFormat = (d) => {
  return `${d.getFullYear()}/${(d.getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`
}

console.log(toFormat(d));
```